# Series Uniform Convergence Question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Let $M>0$.
$$\sum_{n=M}^{\infty} \frac {1}{(x-n)^2}$$

How do I show this converges uniformly for $x ≤ \frac{|M|}{2}$

My actual question is how do I determine the interval of uniform convergence for general series like this one.

Am I allowed to use the Weierstrass M test? Because the sum is between $M$ and $\infty$.

$\sum_{n=M}^{\infty} \frac {1}{(x-n)^2}≤\sum_{n=M}^{\infty} \frac {1}{n^2}$ which converges so the series converges uniformly for all $x$?

Comment: What is $x$? If $x \in \mathbb Z$ and $x \geq M$ then there will be a problem...

Comment: Edited my question

Answer (score 1):

In fact, this series converges uniformly in $(-\infty,M-\varepsilon]$, for every $\varepsilon>0$, since if $x\in(-\infty,M-\varepsilon]$, then 
$$
0<\frac{1}{(x-n)^2}\le \frac{1}{(M-\varepsilon-n)^2},\quad\text{for all $n\ge M$},
$$
and hence
$$
0<\sum_{n\ge M}\frac{1}{(x-n)^2}\le \sum_{n\ge M}\frac{1}{(M-\varepsilon-n)^2},\quad\text{for all $n\ge M$}.
$$
Hence, it suffices to show that the series $\sum_{n\ge M}\frac{1}{(M-\varepsilon-n)^2}$ converges. To do this observe that
$$
\sum_{n\ge M}\frac{1}{(M-\varepsilon-n)^2}=\frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}+
\sum_{n\ge M+1}\frac{1}{(M-\varepsilon-n)^2}\le\frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}+
\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{n^2}.
$$

Comment: How do I show it converges uniformly for x≤|M|/2?

Comment: Let epsilon be M/2 in your answer?